# How to override the system timezone in settings.php?

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to override the site's timezone in settings.local.php.

Looking at the config file, this should be simple:

```
$ more system.date.yml
country:
  default: ''
first_day: 0
timezone:
  default: UTC
  user:
    configurable: true
    warn: false
    default: 0
```

but I've trying various combinations of this and none of them work:

```
$config['system.date']['timezone']['default'] = 'Europe/London';
$config['system.date.timezone.default'] = 'Europe/London';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example (`$config['system.date']['timezone']['default'] = 'Europe/London';`) is the correct way to override config values in your settings.php file.

It sounds like you've hit [an issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2408549) noted in the [config override system docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/configuration-override-system):

> Note that values overridden via $config within `settings.php` **will not be viewable from the Drupal administration** interface (until #2408549: There is no indication on configuration forms if there are overridden values is fixed, until then you can use Configuration Override Warn or Config Override Inspector) or from inspection via drush (unless you add the `--include-overridden` flag). The administration interface displays the values stored in configuration so that you can stage changes to other environments that don't have the overrides.

So if you view `/admin/config/regional/settings` page or the `drush cget system.date timezone.default` command, it won't show the overridden value.

You can try something like `drush cget --include-overridden system.date timezone.default` or
`drush eval 'print \Drupal::config("system.date")->get("timezone.default");'` to confirm your overridden value is actually being set in your settings.php